# Remove Single Char in String Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, function, python-2.7

I have written the above program. The program supposed to do remove chr from str if str has chr in it and character follow chr is different than chr.

Can anyone here help me what's going on this? Why is not working as supposed? I see some problems with function calling inside a function.

```
def removesingleton(str,chr):
    '''
    (str,str)->(str)
    Returns str with removed single chr 
    >>>removesingleton("Welcomee","e")
    Wlcomee
    >>>removesingleton("XabXXaX","X")
    abXXa
    '''
    output, index = "", 0
    if str:
        for char in str:
            if char == chr:
                if index+1 < len(str) and str[index+1] == chr:
                    output += str[:index+2]
                    removesingleton(str[index+2:],chr)
                else:
                    removesingleton(str[index+1:],chr)
            else:
                output += str[index]
                removesingleton(str[index+1:],chr)   
            index += 1
    return output

print removesingleton("XabXXaX","X")
```

Comment: I see you're calling `removesingleton` inside `removesingleton`. But you don't do anything with the result. Shouldn't you be assigning it somewhere, or something?

Comment: You shouldn't use `str` and `chr` as variable names - they shadow built-ins

Comment: @Kevin I actually use them to send the sliced string to function. So that I will add the characters that I already added to output. I see there are problems with function calling. But I can't figure it out myself.

Comment: What happens when you run this? Peppering the code with logging statements to watch certain values that are changed is often the most helpful debugging I've ever done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of the recursive calls. They're completely unnecessary, since you're doing a loop over the whole string within the single call. (You were also ignoring the return value, so there was not much point in recursing in the first place.)

What you do need is to check both the next character and the previous one to see if the current character is part of a repeated sequence. You don't need to do any slicing, nor do you even need an explicit loop. Here's a working version of the code, distilled down to a single generator expression inside a `str.join` call:

```
def removesingleton(s, ch):
    '''
    (str,str)->(str)
    Returns a copy of s with all non-repeated instances of ch removed 
    >>>removesingleton("Welcomee","e")
    Wlcomee
    >>>removesingleton("XabXXaX","X")
    abXXa
    '''
    return "".join(c for i, c in enumerate(s)     # enumerate gives us our index
                   if c != ch or          # keep any of:  non-matching characters
                      (i > 0 and s[i-1] == ch) or       # previous character was the same
                      (i < len(s)-1 and s[i+1] == ch))  # next character is the same
```